# Error when adding a new object into existing javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to resolve an issue of the cannot read property of undefined error when I try to add a new object I created into my javascript file.

Previously, I was able to successfully get 3 objects (a cow, plane, and teapot) in a scene on html and interact with them. When I went to replace the plane with my own object (in my case it is called willis), I received the error.

The error spicifically states:

prog4.js:131 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'positions' of undefined(…)
init 
@ prog4.js:131
onload 
@ prog4.html:12

I have changed nothing about the code, other than renaming 'plane' to 'willis' and making sure the files were in the correct locations.

Any help very much appreciated! My goal is to get 3 different objects in the scene from the original 3 and I was hoping to do it one at a time to see the progress.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-matrix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teapot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="willis.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prog4.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        precision mediump float;

        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
        uniform vec4 lightPosition;

        attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 vertexNormal;

        varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
        varying vec3 fragmentLight;
        varying vec3 fragmentView;
        varying vec4 fragmentPosition;

        void main() {        
            mat4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

            vec4 p = vec4 (modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition);
            vec4 q = vec4 (viewMatrix * lightPosition);

            fragmentNormal = normalize(mat3(modelViewMatrix) * vertexNormal);
            fragmentLight  = normalize(vec3(q - p));
            fragmentView   = normalize(vec3(-p));
            fragmentPosition = vertexPosition;

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;

        }
    </script>
    <script id="lightingFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
        varying vec3 fragmentLight;
        varying vec3 fragmentView;

        uniform vec3 modelColor;
        uniform vec3 lightColor;


        void main() {      
          vec3 n = normalize(fragmentNormal);
          vec3 l = normalize(fragmentLight);
          vec3 v = normalize(fragmentView);
          vec3 h = normalize(l+v);

          float d = max(dot(l,n),0.0);
          float s = pow(max(dot(h,n),0.0), 10.0);

          vec3 fragmentColor = modelColor * lightColor * d + lightColor * s;

          gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0);

        }
    </script>
    <script id="rainbowFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
        varying vec3 fragmentLight;
        varying vec3 fragmentView;
        varying vec4 fragmentPosition;

        uniform vec3 lightColor;

        void main() {

            vec3 modelColor;

            if(fragmentPosition.y > 0.5) {
                modelColor = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
            else if (fragmentPosition.y > 0.3) {
                modelColor = vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
            }
            else if (fragmentPosition.y > 0.1) {
                modelColor = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.1);
            }
            else {
                modelColor = vec3(0.0,1.0,1.0);
            }

        vec3 fragmentColor = modelColor;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0);
    }
    </script>
    <script id="goochFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
        varying vec3 fragmentLight;
        varying vec3 fragmentView;

        uniform vec3 modelColor;
        uniform vec3 lightColor;

        void main() {      
          vec3 n = normalize(fragmentNormal);
          vec3 l = normalize(fragmentLight);
          vec3 v = normalize(fragmentView);
          vec3 h = normalize(l+v);

          float kg = max(dot(n,v), 0.0);

          vec3 fragmentColor = mix(vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0), vec3(1.0,1.0,0.0), kg);

          gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0);

        }
    </script>
    <canvas id="webgl" width="500px" height="500px" >
        This content requires <a href="http://get.webgl.org/">WebGL</a>.
    </canvas>
</body>
```

```
var canvas
var gl

var willis
var teapot
var cow

// Interaction
var modelRotationX =0;
var modelRotationY =0;

var dragging = false;
var lastClientX = 0;
var lastClientY = 0;

// Mouse commands
function onmousedown(event) {  
    dragging = true;
    lastClientX = event.clientX;
    lastClientY = event.clientY;
}

function onmouseup(event) {
    dragging = false;
}

function onmousemove(event) {
    if (dragging) {
        dX = event.clientX - lastClientX;
        dY = event.clientY - lastClientY;

        modelRotationY = modelRotationY + dX;
        modelRotationX = modelRotationX + dY;

        if (modelRotationX > 90.0) {
            modelRotationX = 90.0;
        }
        if (modelRotationX < -90.0) {
            modelRotationX = -90.0;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    lastClientX = event.clientX;
    lastClientY = event.clientY;
}

// FLatten
function flatten(a) {
    return a.reduce(function (b, v) { b.push.apply(b, v); return b }, [])
}

// Create shaders for objects
function Shader (vertexId, fragmentId) {
    this.program = createProgram(gl, document.getElementById(vertexId).text,
                                     document.getElementById(fragmentId).text);
    this.projectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "projectionMatrix");
    this.viewMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "viewMatrix");
    this.modelMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "modelMatrix");

    this.lightPositionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "lightPosition");
    this.modelColorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "modelColor");
    this.lightColorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "lightColor");

    this.vertexPositionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexPosition');
    this.vertexNormalLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexNormal');

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexPositionLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexNormalLocation);
}

// Execution for shaders
Shader.prototype.use = function(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix) {
    gl.useProgram(this.program);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.viewMatrixLocation, false, viewMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.modelMatrixLocation, false, modelMatrix.elements);

    gl.uniform4f(this.lightPositionLocation,0,8,8,1);
    gl.uniform3f(this.modelColorLocation,1,1,1);
    gl.uniform3f(this.lightColorLocation,0.6,0.4,0.2);
}

// Create models
function Model (positions, normals, triangles) {
    this.positionArray = new Float32Array(flatten(positions));
    this.normalArray = new Float32Array(flatten(normals));
    this.triangleArray = new Uint16Array(flatten(triangles));

    this.normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    this.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    this.triangleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Draw shaders on objects
Model.prototype.draw = function (shader_entry) {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_entry.vertexNormalLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_entry.vertexPositionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.triangleArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);   
}

// Initialization
function init() {
    // Initialize the GL context
    canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas, false);

    lightingShader = new Shader('vertexShader', 'lightingFragmentShader');
    rainbowShader = new Shader('vertexShader', 'rainbowFragmentShader');
    goochShader = new Shader('vertexShader', 'goochFragmentShader');

    teapotModel = new Model(teapot.positions, teapot.normals, teapot.triangles);
    willisModel = new Model(willis.positions, willis.normals, willis.triangles);
    cowModel = new Model(cow.positions, cow.normals, cow.triangles);

    // Make mouse functions "properties of the canvas entity."
    canvas.onmousedown = onmousedown;  
    canvas.onmouseup = onmouseup;
    canvas.onmousemove = onmousemove;

    // Depth test
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // Request animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Draw
function draw() {

    // Create colored background
    gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.3);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Declaration of variables
    var modelMatrix = new Matrix4();
    var viewMatrix = new Matrix4();
    var projectionMatrix = new Matrix4();

    // Cow and rotation
    var modelMatrix = new Matrix4();
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationX,1,0,0);
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationY,0,1,0);
    viewMatrix.translate(0,0,-5)

    projectionMatrix.perspective(60,1,1,10);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // Cow shader
    lightingShader.use(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
    cowModel.draw(lightingShader);

    // willis
    var modelMatrix = new Matrix4();
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationX,1,0,0);
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationY,0,1,0);
    viewMatrix.translate(2,0,-1)

    // willis shader
    goochShader.use(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
    willisModel.draw(goochShader);

    //Teapot
    var modelMatrix = new Matrix4();
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationX,1,0,0);
    modelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationY,0,1,0);
    viewMatrix.translate(-5,0,-2)

    // Teapot shader
    rainbowShader.use(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
    teapotModel.draw(rainbowShader);
}
```

Comment: You have `teapot.positions, teapot.normals, teapot.triangles`, but never assigned anything to `teapot`. The same thing for `willis` and `cow`.

Comment: Can you keep your problem local and avoid unnecessary code to help people provide better responses?

Comment: WAY too much code to look at. Please create a minimal example of a couple dozen lines.